# Cut and transpose some lines of a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have 1344 rows of data column. I want to form 32 row by 42 columns from my input data file. I want to cut the first 42 row and paste to one raw of 42 column data and continue down likewise. My data is arranged as

file name: data.txt

```
1
2
3
.
.
.
1344
```

I want the result be 
output.txt

```
1 2 3 ....42
43 44      84
.
.
.
1303 1304 . . . 1344
```

I want you help me with a script that can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These should work:

```
awk '{if(n==41){n=0;print $0}else{printf "%s ",$0;n++}}' data.txt
```

or

```
awk '{if(NR % 42 == 0){print;}else{printf "%s ",$0}}' data.txt
```

or

```
perl -ne 'if($. % 42){chomp; print "$_ "}else{ print;}' data.txt
```

or

```
perl -pne 's/\n/ / if $. % 42' data.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `rs` command - if it is available:

```
< original.file rs 0 42 > reshaped.file
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
COUNT=0
while read data
do
  echo -n "${data} "
  let COUNT=${COUNT}+1;
  if (( ${COUNT} % 42  == 0 ))
  then
    echo ""
  fi
done < data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you could use python, numpy is quite well suited for this. Assuming a file `x.txt` contains the data, you could do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np

a=np.loadtxt('x.txt', dtype='int') # load array from file x.txt into variable a
print a
b=a.reshape(32,42) # reshape array to desired shape
print b
c=a.T # Do a transpose if required
print c
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using paste

Only because I love using `paste` so much, you can actually do this with `paste`, though it isn't pretty:

#### Sample data

```
$ seq 100 > data.txt
```

#### Example

```
$ paste -d " " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - < data.txt
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84
85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

If you need to control the number of columns, then add/remove the corresponding  amount of dashes from `paste`.

You can get fancy and use a loop to control the generation of the dashes to `paste` like so:

```
$ paste -d " " $(for i in $(seq 42); do echo "- ";done) < data.txt 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84
85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Further enhancements can be made to the loop. Instead of using `seq` we can use the shells brace expansion `{#...#}`.

```
$ paste -d " " $(for i in {1..42}; do echo "- ";done) < data.txt
```

#### Using xargs

Another less obvious method would be to make `xargs` do the controlling of the number of characters through its `-n #` switch.

```
$ seq 100 | xargs -n 42
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84
85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

So we could leverage this method like so:

```
$ xargs -n 42 < data.txt 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84
85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

These methods will only work when the data we're dealing with is space delimited. Also of note with the `xargs` method, this is by default, just echoing out the arguments, but it could be modified so that it could perform an action for each of the arguments as well.

Comment: The `xargs` one is brilliant!

Comment: @terdon - thanks, these questions are always fun, since we can figure out as many ways as possible to do X. I was going to do it Perl but saw you beaten me to it so I figured I try other ways.